# Trimming the end of a string if it contains a certain character?

Tags: php, string

Let's say I have a string like this: `asdf, asdf, asdf,`. There is a comma and a space at the end. I want to trim that off only if it is a comma and a space. If the string looks like this `asdf, asdf, asdf` then I do not want it to trim off the last two characters. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

rtrim($str, ", ");

That will trim all of the spaces and commas from the right of the string.  It is faster than a regexp.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = preg_replace('~, $~', '', $str);
```